# Conditional fill across a data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame as below:

| x | y | m0 | m1 | m2 | mn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NA | 1 | 5 | NA | NA | NA |
| NA | 2 | 15 | NA | NA | NA |
| 1 | 3 | 25 | NA | NA | NA |

I would like to fill the value in m0 across the number of columns specified in y only where x = NA. Desired result is:

| x | y | m0 | m1 | m2 | mn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NA | 1 | 5 | 5 | NA | NA |
| NA | 2 | 15 | 15 | 15 | NA |
| 1 | 3 | 25 | NA | NA | NA |

Appreciate any guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `mutate` `across` the columns you want to replace using an ifelse like this:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(m1:mn, ~ if_else(is.na(x), m0, NA)))
#>    x m0 m1 m2 mn
#> 1 NA  5  5  5  5
#> 2 NA 15 15 15 15
#> 3  1 25 NA NA NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: bingo this worked, but I've edited the question to add an element I forgot. Sorry! Any thoughts on solution?